# How do i send fluentd logs to elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, fluentd

I am using EFK.
The logs of the apps are sent to elasticsearch via fluentD,
How do I send fluentD's logs to elasticsearch?
Just read the log file from fluentD and send it?

Is there a use case?

Answer (score 0):

There is fluentd elasticsearch plugin: https://docs.fluentd.org/output/elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

You can match and handle fluentd's internal logs just as any other log message with `<match fluent.*>` See [the docs](https://docs.fluentd.org/deployment/logging#capture-fluentd-logs) for more.